# Python Minidom XML parsing interchangable upper and lower case node names

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Hoping for help here. I am writing a small script to pull info from a data file. the following is the start of the xml...its quite big.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<flatNet Version="1" id="{014852F8-3010-4a5f-8215-8F47B000EA60}" sch="Vbt-mbb-1.4.scs">
<partNumbers>
<PartNumber Name="PN_LIB_NAME" Version="1">
<Properties Ver="1">
<a Key="PARTNAME" Value="PART_NAME"/>
<a Key="ALTPARTREF" Value="PART_REF"/>
```

My problem is that in some of the files I need to parse, the  node is capitalized and in some it is lower case.
How do I get the node name (either "a" or "A") into a variable so I can use it for a function?

Else I am stuck changing it manually every time I want to parse a new file depending on what that file contains.

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried at least get the <a/> nodes, then <A/> nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will either have to have 2 nodelists and work with them individually

```
a1 = doc.getElementsByTagName('a')
a2 = doc.getElementsByTagName('A')

#do stuff with a1 and a2
```

or normalize the tags along the lines of this:

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
>>> xml = minidom.parseString('<root><head>hi!</head><body>text<a>blah</a><A>blahblah</A></body></root>')
>>> allEls = xml.getElementsByTagName('*')
>>> for i in allEls:
    if i.localName.lower() == 'a':
        print i.toxml()


<a>blah</a>
<A>blahblah</A>
```